# Core Data w/ a UIImage property - use a UIImage or NSData?

Tags: ios, core-data, uiimage

Been using Core Data for a minute. At some point somewhere in the past, I decided that any image attributes in NSManagedObject subclasses should be instances of NSData. I don't remember exactly what informed that decision, but it's something I learned years ago and have always stuck to since. When I wanted a UIImage, I had a readonly property on my NSManagedObject subclass whose getter would create a UIImage instance from the data using one of the UIImageRepresentation functions.

Now I'm working on a new project, and it occurs to me that Apple's PhotoLocations sample app (Core Data Transformable Attributes) actually uses a UIImage for the persisted property. Why? For simplicity's sake it's certainly easier, no need for that UIImageRepresentation function call.

I'm aware of stuff like "store in external record file" and such, my question isn't about that, or even whether or not images should be in their own entity, related to my original entity - it's simply whether or not I should use UIImage or NSData as the type for a persisted property.

Been hard to figure out what's considered best practice or what the drawback is one way or the other. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I always store data in a format that is readable by anyone.  It makes for data that is easier to transmit, use in multiple systems, avoids deprecation, etc.

When I store an image I store it in a PNG format instead of UIImage.  Why?

- UIImage could change.
- I may want to upload it to a server.
- I may need to read the file on OS X.
- I might want to make it transportable later.

When it comes to data, I like to think past just the here and now.

Comment: So actually, I just came across something that makes me wish I had gone with UIImage instead. I'm having a bug right now around scale factors, and it seems like when I create some NSData from the UIImage using the JPEG function, the scale factor is lost. I'm assuming that if I had persisted the UIImage that value would have been persisted somewhere. So now I'll either have to change the model (eh, the app has shipped, so would prefer to avoid that) or start saving the scale alongside it. Well, for next time!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with changing the model of a shipped app.  Something as simple as adding a column is a very straight-forward migration.  However, I would test to make sure that persisting the UIImage would persist the scale.  I am not certain that it would.